# DELETE CASCADE on a child row delete parent?

Tags: mysql, sql, cascade, cascading-deletes

I have 3 tables.
The last two tables have a foreign key to the first on the same field.
Both foreign keys are set to UPDATE CASCADE, DELETE CASCADE.
When I delete a child-row in the second table, the parent row in the first table remains unchanged.
But when I delete a child-row in the third table, the first row in the table is deleted!

Foreign keys should not behave in the same way as both daughters?

Comment: Please show us your DB schema - preferably in SQLFiddle.

Comment: Excuse me! I solved the problem!

Comment: Can you please put your solution here so that everyone can see it?

Comment: There was **another** foreign key set to delete cascade. I was the bug :)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that table 2 uses MyISAM tables (which do not support foreign keys) while the other two tables are using the InnoDB engine (which do support foreign keys).

[From the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> Foreign key relationships involve a parent table that holds the central data values, and a child table with identical values pointing back to its parent. The FOREIGN KEY clause is specified in the child table. **The parent and child tables must both be InnoDB tables.** They must not be TEMPORARY tables.